# sendVideo gives error 'Bad Request: failed to get HTTP URL content'

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telepot

I have a short url `https://da.gd/D8GwGt` which is a download link for a video. When I try to send this video using `bot.sendVideo(chat_id, https://da.gd/D8GwGt, supports_streaming=True)` it gives out an error as

```
telepot.exception.TelegramError: ('Bad Request: failed to get HTTP URL content', 400, {'ok': False, 'error_code': 400, 'description': 'Bad Request: failed to get HTTP URL content'})
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: It must be a direct link to the file, other than that It happens sometime with some links, I've had this experience mostly with instagram content. You have to download the link with your server and then upload it to telegram.

Comment: should I use the requests library to get the content? @AliPadida

Comment: yes, download the file using requests library and then upload it